# D3 zoomable treemap - loading new levels async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js, treemap

In this Treemap example, the whole JSON tree exists from the start:
http://jsfiddle.net/6p1gayrp/

As I have a very big dataset, I would like to load each level on click:
Clicking "International relations" in the example should instead load the children array from a remote datasource and then layout the rectangles.

So starting out with one level:

```
var json = {
    "name": "Sitemap",
    "children": [{
        "name": "International Relations",
        "value" : 700
    }]
}
```

And then adding more data to the tree before recalculating layout:

```
var json = {
    "name": "Sitemap",
    "children": [{
        "name": "International Relations",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Systemic Theory",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Great Powers",
                "value": 400,
            }, {
                "name": "Systemic Politics",
                "value": 300,
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

**How can I load data async while keeping the rest of the functionality intact?**

(Ideally this would also work in the other direction: For example if a user navigates straight to a particular level of the treemap and then starts going up the hierarchy.)

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle, then may be I can help. thanks

Comment: have u done anything where are u lacking......